# A "save to file" method in Javascript works remotely but not locally

Tags: javascript, html

I found on stackoverflow a link to a FileSaver.js demo : 
https://eligrey.com/demos/FileSaver.js/

It works on that site. You can write some text in a field, click on "Save", and a dialog box opens up, asking you where you want to save the file.

I copied the page source locally. I doesn't work. No buttons to click, and the field where the text to be saved should be entered displays the javascript code instead.

There are three parts in that code. One for saving a picture, one for saving plain text, one for saving formatted text.

If I delete the first two parts, the third part at least displays properly. But if I click "Save", no dialog box appears. Firefox briefly says it is connecting (to what?), and then nothing.

There are additional libraries, but they are all fully linked (I mean, no local links such as ./something.js - they are linked with their full url). 
Anyway, I tried downloading them and using local links, the result is the same.

It is not a matter of browser, because I'm visiting the remote site and my local copy with the same Firefox.

It is not a matter of security, because obviously locally creating a text file and saving it on my own computer cannot be more insecure than doing the same thing via somebody else's server.

Can someone please tell me what I've missed? How can I get this code to function locally?

Comment: Without seeing yours, we can't possibly know why it isn't working - any answer you'd get at this point would *have* to be a guess, which is a major red flag that the question is not complete. On top of that, it seems a little too broad.

Comment: Thank you Santi. What details should I give to make my question less broad? I don't know what to add...

Comment: Consider reading the site's [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. The main issue is that StackOverflow is a place to go when you have some code, and a specific portion or line isn't working. However questions like "How can I do something like such-and-such?" or "Why is this not working? (without any code)" are often closed and considered off-topic.

Comment: <section id="html-demo">
<div class="input" id="html" contenteditable="">
<ul>
<li><del>Plain</del> <ins>Boring</ins> text.</li>
<li><em>Emphasized text!</em></li>
<li><strong>Strong text!</strong></li>
</ul>
</div>
<form id="html-options">
<label>Filename: <input type="text" class="filename" id="html-filename" placeholder="a rich document"/>.xhtml</label>
<input type="submit" value="Save"/>
</form>
</section>

Comment: And there are 4 links to libraries:

Comment: <script async="" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/eligrey/Blob.js/0cef2746414269b16834878a8abc52eb9d53e6bd/Blob.js"/>
    
<script async="" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/eligrey/canvas-toBlob.js/f1a01896135ab378aa5c0118eadd81da55e698d8/canvas-toBlob.js"/>
    
<script async="" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/e9d941381475b5df8b7d7691013401e171014e89/FileSaver.min.js"/>
    
<script async="" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/597b6cd0207ce408a6d34890b5b2826b13450714/demo/demo.js"/>